# Attach and upgrade TFS 2005 databases to a TFS 2008 installation

Tags: tfs, upgrade

I have a Windows server 2008 with SQL 2008 and TFS 2008 installed. And I have another box with SQL 2005 and TFS 2005 installed. Does anyone know of a way I can just transfer the databases (or data in another way) from TFS 2005 to TFS 2008. Any data on the 2008 box can be deleted.

The machines are not in a domain so all accounts are local. So I'll have to fix that afterwards, but that's managable.

Basically, can I attach the databases and run an upgrade command?

Comment: This *might* be more appropriate on serverfault.com... but I'd like to see what answers appear here first.

Comment: Yeah, it might. I asked it at the site with the most questions tagged "tfs" :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this is a supported option. Please see:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FF12844F-398C-4FE9-8B0D-9E84181D9923&displaylang=en

jMM